# I'm new to XML and the file I'm writing for an app keeps getting returned as malformed

Tags: xml, phonegap

I'm just starting with XML and writing a config page for a phonegap app I'm developing.  For some reason it always returns the file as malformed unless I remove the top line but then the app wont open when I build it.  Any help would be great.

I've tried removing the top line, changing the quotation marks but can't find any solutions and I've never worked with XML before.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    id        = "com.aedwards.title"
    versionCode="10"
    version   = "1.0.0" >
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

If that XML snippet the whole file then the problem is simply that there is no end tag for `<widget>`.

Your last line should be

```
version   = "1.0.0" />
```

or

```
version   = "1.0.0" ></widget>
```

Comment: No I've got more to the file its just that it only brings up the malformed xml error while the top line is included but if it isn't in then the app wont work when I download  it to my device.  I do have a closing tag for widget.

Comment: Well, the first line is a standard xml header so I have no idea what's going wrong.